# Improve WCF performance for large arrays

Tags: performance, wcf, protobuf-net

We are using WCF for transferring data from a server application to several clients. Actually, for most of the traffic, client and server are running on the same machine, so I would expect the transfer to be really fast.

However, when transferring large arrays (16-bit grayscale images), it takes several seconds until the data is transferred. For a 16 MB image, it takes around 3-5 seconds!

Initially, we were using `ushort` arrays because it is the most suitable data type for storing 16-bit grayscale image data. However, this was extremely slow: something around 20-25 seconds for 16 MB. When we copy the data to a `byte` array before serialization using `Buffer.BlockCopy`, it is reduced to 3-5 seconds for some reason. However, 3-5 seconds for transferring 16 MB from one application to another running on the same machine still seems far too long to me!

Therefore, my question is: **How can we improve the performance for such a scenario?**

I already investigated protobuf-net from Marc Gravell, but I am uncertain whether it would help in this case... Any experiences or other suggestions?

Here is the source code of one of our data classes (containing the image data):

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class ImageData
{
    private ushort[] m_pixelData;

    public ushort[] PixelData
    {
        get
        {
            return m_pixelData;
        }
        set
        {
            m_pixelData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PixelData");
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public override byte[] FileData
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.PixelData == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return ListHelper.ConvertToByteArray(this.PixelData);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                this.PixelData = null;
                return;
            }

            this.PixelData = ListHelper.ConvertToUshortArray(value);
        }
    }

}
```

Note that only the `FileData` property is marked as `[DataMember]`, so that the `PixelData` property is not serialized!

Here are the relevant parts of the server's `app.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="Services.ImageDataService" behaviorConfiguration="ServicesBehavior">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8008/ImageDataService" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBindingLargeFileTransfer" contract="Services.IImageDataService" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServicesBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding
                name="NetTcpBindingLargeFileTransfer"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" closeTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="infinite" sendTimeout="infinite"
                transactionFlow="false" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                transferMode="Buffered" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2097152" maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824">
                <readerQuotas
                    maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="infinite" enabled="false" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And the client's `app.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding
                name="NetTcpBindingLargeFileTransfer"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" closeTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="infinite" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                transactionFlow="false" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                transferMode="Buffered" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2097152" maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824">
                <readerQuotas
                    maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="infinite" enabled="false" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint
            address="net.tcp://localhost:8008/ImageDataService"
            binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBindingLargeFileTransfer"
            contract="Services.IImageDataService"
            name="Services.IImageDataService"
            behaviorConfiguration="ServicesBehavior" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServicesBehavior">
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"></dataContractSerializer>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the same machine try named pipes.

[Choosing a Transport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! This reduced the transfer time to half the time! I did not think of this one since there are also remote clients, i.e. on other machines. However, the image data is typically not transferred across the network. So adding another endpoint using `NetNamedPipeBinding` is a feasible approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try streaming with named pipe transport. For details please see this post [Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)

It may be a problem with buffering your data before sending it to server/client. Streaming will send your data in chunks.

Comment: I already had a look at streaming some time ago. However, it even made it slower unfortunately. Maybe the amount of data is not large enough to have a performance gain by streaming. From what I read on the internet I got the impression that streaming is more meant for really large data items like 500 MB or so.

Comment: Did you also try it with named pipes?

Comment: As written above (other answer), the named pipes reduced the transfer time to half the time.